# какая здесь рекурентная формула?

Tags: c++, математика, рекурсия

Визначити закономірність формування послідовності,
записати рекурентне співвідношення для n-го члена послідовності.
Реалізувати рекурсивну функцію обчислення n-го члена послідовності.
Обчислити 7-й член послідовності. Оцінити складність алгоритму.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Помогите найти формулу и составить функцию**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простейшая -

```
a(n) = a(n-1)^2 + a(n-2)^2
```

Откровенно - не понимаю, откуда столько однотипных простых вопросов. Что, все двоечники с одной группы прибежали? :)

Функцию уж, знаете, напишите сами - тем более что тут седьмой член 750797 вполне в `int` помещается, вообще никаких проблем.